# Merge into copied file

Tags: svn, merge

Let's say I make a svn copy of /trunk and call it /branches/v1

now in /branches/v1 I make an svn copy of file A called file B

when I merge changes from /trunk to /branches/v1, changes to file A in trunk are merged into file A in the branch, but they aren't merged into file B. If file A was renamed to B rather than copied, it would have merged them into B.

This behaviour seems counter-intuitive to me because I thought a SVN rename was a copy followed by a delete. Is this by design? is there any way of changing it?

Answer (score -1):

SVN will *never* merge into a renamed file. 
It will generate a tree conflict. see the chapter in svnbook [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.tour.treeconflicts.example).

Never rename a file(or a dir) in a branch. And never rename a file in trunk as long as you want to merge back into it. This leaves the question when you can use renaming and merging? The answer is bitter: never!

Renaming and Merging just doesn't work together (in SVN).

Comment: You **LIE** in "Renaming and Merging just doesn't work together (in SVN)." They work (with small trick)

Comment: calm down badger.. it is only a website. Also you say by yourself: "They work (with a small trick)". So instead voting down and calling me a liar(which is quite rude), just write your own answer and show us the trick. If it is a trick, I may be not a liar, but just an unenlightened guy. So share your knowledge(bw, this website is for sharing knowledge, not rude accusations). SVN cannot track merges over renames. This is all I want to say. You may can tweak it on some places but SVN is not the tool for doing this job very well.